# DPDK Number of ports must be even

Tags: dpdk

I spent some time trying to figure out how to fix the "number of ports must be even" error. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158970/dpdk-number-of-ports-must-be-even-one-ethernet-device) which explains how to run DPDK inside a VM. I was wondering if there is a solution that does not require one.

My platform: Debian 10, Linux 5.8 (on a laptop) with an e1000e NIC driver

What I want to do: Make the skeleton (basicfwd) app work

My problem: [rte_eth_dev_count_avail](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#a9ab708089665bebcd65cefe5383b24f2) returns 0

What I did up until now: [I followed the documentation](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html) and tried to setup a vfio_pci driver to my ethernet device.

Two things:

- When I bind a device with the vfio_pci driver it loses its IP
  interface
- I can't create VF devices because I can't write in /sys/bus/pci/devices/ even when I `su root`

The skeleton program is not working with this so I tried using another driver.

I bound the device to the uio_pci_generic driver. It does bind to it but the app still doesn't work. Here is the `dpdk-devbind.py --status` output:

```
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:00:1f.6 'Device 0d4f' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=e1000e
```

What happens when I launch the program:

```
$ sudo ./build/examples/dpdk-skeleton -l 0-3 -n 4 -a 0000:00:1f.6 

EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Error: number of ports must be even
```

Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated !

Comment: DPDk Skeleton requires even ports, minimum 2 ports https://doc.dpdk.org/dts/test_plans/skeleton_test_plan.html. One can create 2 VF under Kernel PF and bind the VF to igb_uio or vfio_pci

Comment: Thank you @VipinVarghese for this answer. I understand that the app needs an even number of ports to work. The problem is that DPDK is not picking up the device and is not able to open any port. As I mentioned, rte_eth_dev_count_avail returns 0.
Do you have an idea as to why is DPDK not picking up the device ?

Comment: 2 possible causes 1) applciation is compiled in shared library or 2) the PMD is not Built. I can make my self available on skype for quick debugging if required?

Comment: Yes sure, I do not have a skype handle tho, can I send you a fidji link ?

Comment: The program is indeed compiled with shared libraries. Could you tell me more about how to build a PMD ? Do you mean binding the device to a dpdk-compatible driver ?

Comment: If it is a shared library built mode, please change the cmdline to `sudo ./build/examples/dpdk-skeleton -l 0-3 -n 4 -a 0000:00:1f.6  -d librte_net_e1000.so --log-level=pmd,8`.

Comment: There is the output of that command. It seems like I have a static DPDK build after all...
```EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: UIO_RESOURCE_LIST tailq is already registered
PANIC in tailqinitfn_rte_uio_tailq():```

Comment: hmm, now I am bit confused requires live debug skypw, zoom, hangout?

Comment: will share within a hour

Comment: updated answer, accept and upvote to close the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VM I am able to get e1000 bind with the following steps

1. Start VM with `82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller`
2. Download and build DPDK 21.02
3. insmod igb_uio or modprobe uio_pci_generic
4. bind with vfio-pci fails with `vfio-pci: probe of 0000:00:08.0 failed with error -22`
5. start the application with `./a.out -l 1 --log-level=pmd,8`

build application: `gcc basicfwd.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags --static libdpdk`

Logs:

```
e1000_null_phy_generic(): e1000_null_phy_generic
e1000_read_phy_reg_m88(): e1000_read_phy_reg_m88
e1000_null_ops_generic(): e1000_null_ops_generic
e1000_read_phy_reg_mdic(): e1000_read_phy_reg_mdic
e1000_null_phy_generic(): e1000_null_phy_generic
e1000_read_phy_reg_m88(): e1000_read_phy_reg_m88
e1000_null_ops_generic(): e1000_null_ops_generic
e1000_read_phy_reg_mdic(): e1000_read_phy_reg_mdic
e1000_null_phy_generic(): e1000_null_phy_generic
e1000_setup_copper_link_generic(): Unable to establish link!!!
e1000_setup_link_generic(): Initializing the Flow Control address, type and timer regs
e1000_set_fc_watermarks_generic(): e1000_set_fc_watermarks_generic
e1000_clear_hw_cntrs_82540(): e1000_clear_hw_cntrs_82540
e1000_clear_hw_cntrs_base_generic(): e1000_clear_hw_cntrs_base_generic
e1000_check_for_copper_link_generic(): e1000_check_for_copper_link
e1000_phy_has_link_generic(): e1000_phy_has_link_generic
e1000_read_phy_reg_m88(): e1000_read_phy_reg_m88
e1000_null_ops_generic(): e1000_null_ops_generic
e1000_read_phy_reg_mdic(): e1000_read_phy_reg_mdic
e1000_null_phy_generic(): e1000_null_phy_generic
e1000_read_phy_reg_m88(): e1000_read_phy_reg_m88
e1000_null_ops_generic(): e1000_null_ops_generic
e1000_read_phy_reg_mdic(): e1000_read_phy_reg_mdic
e1000_null_phy_generic(): e1000_null_phy_generic
e1000_null_ops_generic(): e1000_null_ops_generic
eth_em_dev_init(): port_id 0 vendorID=0x8086 deviceID=0x100e
```

note: unmodified skeleton requires an even number of ports to work properly.

Hence there is no issue with e1000 and DPDK usability

[EDIT-1] had a live debug with Jeremy, the issue is now reproduced on a physical machine with physical NIC (an not emulated e1000). Checking the PCIe details the physical NIC is not in the list of supported [Intel DPDK NIC](http://core.dpdk.org/supported/nics/intel/). Requested to use a physical NIC recommend from DPDK.